# Couldn't deploy a dynamic web project on WildFly server in Eclipse

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

Created a spring dynamic web project on Eclipse and is running fine on Tomcat and now installed WildFly 9.0.2 final release.

Server is running fine and able to see on  `http://localhost:8080/` saying "Welcome to WildFly 9.. Your WildFly 9 is running."

Are there any dependencies other than below to be added to `pom.xml`. We are facing 404 error. Also please let us know any other ways to check everything is fine or not?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

With WildFly, you should use the `wildfly-maven-plugin`. And you should configure it as a plugin, not as a dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</plugin>
```